# Cannot deploy application with JSF 1.2 on Weblogic 12c

Tags: java, jsf, weblogic12c, jsf-1.2

I have an application that uses JSF 1.2 (Mojarra implementation) and is working fine on Weblogic 10.3.6. Now we are trying to migrate it to Weblogic 12c. We followed the recommendations specified [here](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12213/wls/WBAPP/configurejsfandjtsl.htm#WBAPP207) but it still generates a strange error on deployment:

```
<Sep 16, 2018 6:37:17,576 PM EEST> <Warning> <HTTP> <BEA-101162> <User defined listener com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener failed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/faces/application/ApplicationWrapper.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/faces/application/ApplicationWrapper
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.defineClassInternal(GenericClassLoader.java:1113)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.defineClass(GenericClassLoader.java:1046)

.........................................

    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper
            at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:1029)
            at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:990)
            at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.doFindClass(GenericClassLoader.java:611)
            at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:543)
            at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:496)
            at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:473)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
            at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
            at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.defineClassInternal(GenericClassLoader.java:1113)
            at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.defineClass(GenericClassLoader.java:1046)
            at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:1038)
            at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:990)
            at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.doFindClass(GenericClassLoader.java:611)
            at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:543)
            at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:496)
            at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:473)
            at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
            at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
            at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1825)
            at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getImplGivenPreviousImpl(FactoryFinder.java:517)
            at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getImplementationInstance(FactoryFinder.java:405)
            at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.access$400(FactoryFinder.java:135)
            at javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:717)
            at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:239)
            at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.verifyFactoriesExist(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:187)
            at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:132)
            at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:204)
            at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:200)
```

Any idea? I cannot upgrade the JSF version for the moment. 
All JSF 1.2 related jars are included in the EAR deployed (in APP-INF/lib). The weblogic-application.xml contains the proper configuration:

```
<wls:prefer-application-packages>
        <wls:package-name>org.hibernate.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>antlr.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>org.springframework.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>org.apache.commons.net.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>javax.faces.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>com.sun.faces.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>com.bea.faces.*</wls:package-name>
    </wls:prefer-application-packages>
    <wls:prefer-application-resources>
        <wls:resource-name>javax.faces.*</wls:resource-name>
        <wls:resource-name>com.sun.faces.*</wls:resource-name>
        <wls:resource-name>com.bea.faces.*</wls:resource-name>
        <wls:resource-name>META-INF/services/javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer</wls:resource-name>
    </wls:prefer-application-resources>
```

What I concluded so far from the error is that the configurations to use JSF 1.2 worked (the class is complaining about is not in JSF 1.2) but I cannot find what who is looking for this class and why (in the code is not used anywhere, obviously since the code is 1.2 compliant)

Comment: `configurations to use JSF 1.2 worked` Mmh not sure about that. Why would be the server trying to search that library, then? Have you tried with the last part of the docs (`library-ref`)?

Comment: I also deployed the library jar file (jsf-1.2.jar) as mentioned in the documentation and refer it with library-ref in weblogic-application.xml. Same problem. I assumed the configurations for JSF 1.2 worked because since it is ok not to find that class (is available from 2.0) what is not ok is who and why is trying to look for it :).